Compiler warning: found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
I am running a g++ compiler command and get the warning
ld: warning: ignoring file 'path/libclass.a[31](energy_injection.o)': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64' 

for a whole range of libs, not just the lib above. I can't find any reference to this warning online.
Did I install the wrong version of some code?

Check your processor arm/amd depends on it lib will change. They are both different processor architecture and will required to download based on your architecture of processor which seems arm.
